# Different exposure time for black resin?

Tags: resin, sainsmart-kumitsu-kl9

I am running test prints on a new Sainsmart Kumitsu KL-9, a large hobby-market resin printer with a price/volume hard to beat.

I had two of the test prints detach from the printing plate and fall into the vat. Standard settings are in place:

[image: Chitu Slicer settings]

I am using a [pitch black Elegoo resin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B081YMD1GN). Does black resin generally require thinner slicing, or longer exposure times? The bottle recommends 60s and 8s, matching the default settings for the printer...

Suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Transmission in the visible light and UV can be different. If they recommend the same exposure, why doubting it? or did you test and find issues?

Comment: Indeed. A few layers attach to the printing plate, and a few layers attach to the transparent bottom of the resin vat. occasionally, there is evidence of the print splitting at a layer (print "slipped" on the XY plane).

Comment: Elegoo updated the specs on the Amazon listing to 13-15Seconds and 70 seconds (different from what is listed on the bottle itself), but that still does not work right on a Kumitsu KL9. The mystery continues.